# ERROR AL CONECTAR EL IIS CON LOCALDB

Tags: .net, asp

hola queria sobre este problema de conexion, estoy tratando de publicar con iis una aplicacion con conecctionstring localdb[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Deberías al menos compartir la cadena de conexión a ver si alguien ve algo extraño.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no indicas S.O ni versión de SQL, pero deberías de probar lo siguiente para poder habilitar la conexión remota al SQL.

**1º Verifica el Firewall del sistema donde está el SQL**

- Crea una regla de entrada del puerto 1433 (Normalmente el del SQL, a no ser que lo tengas en otro) y que acepte todas las conexiones.
- Agrega también la exclusión al ejecutable SQLServer.exe

**2º En inicio, SQL Server, en herramientas de configuración:**

- Ejecuta el SQL_Server_Configuration_Manager >
    Selecciona SQL Server Network > Protocolos
    Habilita el protocolo TCP/IP si está inhabilitado.

**3ª Ejecuta el comando services.msc (El panel de servicios)**

- Busca servicio SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) y lo reinicias.

Ahora ya está,

Comment: termine cambiando en configuracion avanzada en el iis la propiedad identity por localsystem y ahi si funciono